# Grid style list - with multiple <ul> and variable <li> tags

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a complex issue, in which I have some generated HTML which I **cannot** change - and I need to display it in a grid fashion.

I will always have 3 ul tags.

These ul's will have a variable number of li's - between 0-5, but the li's will always total 6.

For example, I could have this:

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Or, it could be something like this:

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
<ul>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Now, I always need the layout to be 2 rows of 3 on desktop, and 3 rows of 2 on smaller devices. The width of the li's should be evenly spaced.

I have tried playing around with the flex grid, but the widths of the li's always conform to the width of the Ul rather than the outer container. Does anyone know if anything like this is possible.

I will re-iterate that at the moment, changing the html is not an option.

Comment: This question is quite broad and vague. More details (including any CSS you've tried) would be helpful.

Comment: To have an even amount of item, filling the viewport width, in 2 or 3 coumns is not possible with the existing markup, unless the amount of items in each list is dividable with 2 _and_ 3, for example 6, 12, etc.

Comment: @LGSon - I will always have 6 <li> tags to fill up the viewport. The problem is that they will be split across multiple <ul> tags (always with a variable number in each ranging between 0-5).

Comment: And that's why it will not work, as I wrote in my previous comment. With a small script one could easily remove the inner `</ul><ul>` and problem solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that using Flexbox, so if you **can't** use a script and you **can't** change markup, you can accomplish this with `float`

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  float: left;
  width: calc(33.333% - 10px);
  margin: 5px;
  height: 30px;
  background: lightgray;
}

/* for wider screens, such as desktop */
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  li {
    width: calc(50% - 10px);
  }
}
```

```html
Markup sample 1

<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>

<div style="clear: both"></div>

Markup sample 2

<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
<ul>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

---

Since your clearly stated you **can't** change markup, but not not using script, here is one with that

Markup sample 1

```js
(function() {
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var uls = document.querySelectorAll('ul');
    for (var i = 1; i < uls.length; i++) {
      var lis = uls[i].querySelectorAll('li');
      for (var j = 0; j < lis.length; j++) {
        uls[0].appendChild(lis[j]);
      }
      uls[i].innerHTML = ''; // make them empty so CSS rule kicks in
    }
  });
})();
```

```css
ul:empty {
  display: none;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  flex-basis: calc(33.333% - 10px);
  margin: 5px;
  height: 30px;
  background: lightgray;
}


/* for wider screens, such as desktop */

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  li {
    width: calc(50% - 10px);
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Markup sample 2

```js
(function() {
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var uls = document.querySelectorAll('ul');
    for (var i = 1; i < uls.length; i++) {
      var lis = uls[i].querySelectorAll('li');
      for (var j = 0; j < lis.length; j++) {
        uls[0].appendChild(lis[j]);        
      }
      uls[i].innerHTML = ''; // make them empty so CSS rule kicks in
    }
  });
})();
```

```css
ul:empty {
  display: none;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  flex-basis: calc(33.333% - 10px);
  margin: 5px;
  height: 30px;
  background: lightgray;
}


/* for wider screens, such as desktop */

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  li {
    width: calc(50% - 10px);
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
<ul>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is brilliant @LGSon, thanks for the in depth answers. I did strip some of the code for my example, which was messing about with my li and ul widths, but your solution has got me back on track. High five!